# IOS app notifications - Notification Center vs Scheduled Summary

Tags: notifications, ios

I have two Scheduled Summaries on my iPhone, iOS 17, and generally it works well.

However, notifications for some apps that are started at the Schedule Summary still show up in the Notification Center (and not the Scheduled Summary).
E.g The settings for this app:

[image: the settings for this app]

show that it's targeted at the Scheduled Summary...

... and yet its notifications show up in the Notification Center:

[image: Notification Center].

(This behavior is not new to iOS 17).

Is this just a bug with the app, or do I need to fix my settings somehow?